# PHP Dealing with MySQL DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have a table where I am displaying the latest administrator notes.  I am only showing the last 3 notes.  I am storing the DATETIME in the database.  What I want to do is be able to say, **if this datetime is less than 3 days old then display this NEW text**.

Now if all 3 notes are in the same day, I want only the latest one to show the NEW text, not all 3.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT note, date_posted, admins.first_name, admins.last_name FROM admin_notes INNER JOIN admins ON admin_notes.admin_id = admins.admin_id ORDER BY date_posted DESC LIMIT 3")) {

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($note_text, $note_date, $note_fname, $note_lname);
        $stmt->store_result();

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td class=\"full\">$note_text<br /><span class=\"from\">".timesince($note_date)." by <strong>$note_fname $note_lname</strong></span></td></tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Does `timesince()` return *New* or are you wanting to output this? You're exact question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$past = new DateTime('-3 days');

// later
$note_datetime = new DateTime($note_date);

if ($note_datetime >= $past) echo 'new';
```

Inspired by the (in the meantime deleted) answer of rkosegi: You can change the query to

```
SELECT note, date_posted, admins.first_name, admins.last_name, (DATEDIFF(NOW(),`date_posted`) < 3) AS isNew FROM [..]
```

Now you get a new "row" `isNew`, that is either 1, oder 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I couldn't get the top PHP part to work, it was showing "new" for the last one which was 3 days old, not for the other two which were 1 and 2 days old.

Comment: As for the query, is there a way to only make the latest one show NEW?  I don't want more than 1 NEW to show at all times even if they are all less than 3 days old.

Comment: First Comment: obviously it must be `>=` and not `<=`. My fault. Second comment: without UNION (which is slightly oversized here) I don't think.